# Facebook share with description -- Android

Tags: android, facebook

Thanks for previous replies,

I am new to Facebook sharing. I am trying to share my image,description and title from my app to Facebook. I am using `facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall`, but I want to share my content with description. Can anyone help me? How do I share all that content in one single post?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At l`private  final void postFacebook(){

```
    String imageurl = "www.xyz.com/123.jpg";
    String caption="your caption", description="Your description", name ="your name",  linkurl=" your link";
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putString("picture", imageurl);
      b.putString("caption",caption);
      b.putString("description",description );
      b.putString("name",name);
      b.putString("link",linkurl);
      try {

          facebookConnector.getFacebook().request("/me/feed", b, "POST");
          //strRet = fb.request("/me/feed",b,"POST");
      }catch(Exception e){

          Log.v(TAG,"Error in posting");
      }

}`
```